# zend 2 и wamp - не работает роутинг

Tags: zend-framework, router, wamp

Нужно поддерживать проект на Zend FW2. Что бы потренироваться решил создать на локальной машине проектик с использованием данной версии фреймворка.
В качестве локального веб-сервера использую wamp.

Роутинг на главную страницу работает ze.localhost/
а на остальные - нет, ze.localhost/admin/

Роутинг прописываю, как:

```
'router' => array(
  'routers' => array(
    'admin' => array(
      'type' => 'literal',
      'options' => array(
        'route' => '/admin/',
        'defaults' => array(
        'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Index',
        'action' => 'index',
```

Встречал в интернете, что данная проблема встречается из-за выключенного mod_rewrite, но в моем случае он включен. 
Прошу помочь, разобраться в данной проблеме. Почему роутинг может не работать?

Comment: Возвращает 404 ошибку

Comment: В httpd.conf открыл Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

Comment: Виртуальный хост прописал, все равно не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю на сколько решение верное, но я еще добавил этот роутинг в \module\Application\config\module.config.php и все заработало. Из чего сделал вывод, что роутинги по дефолту в двух местах.